# Just upgraded to rails 4 and assets not being used in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I just upgraded my [website](http://www.collegeinsideview.com/) from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 (I also upgraded from Ruby 1.9.3 to Ruby 2.0.0). Everything runs fine in development, but not in production. No assets (stylesheets, javascripts, images, favicon etc.) are being used in production.

Why is this, and what could I do to fix it?

I have a hunch that it may have to do with precompiling. I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before running the git commands, and it worked fine, so I don't know what the problem would be. Previously, I had to configure some things to set up precompilation, so maybe those configurations were changed when I upgraded to Rails 4.

logs

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku logs --tail
2014-03-06T13:04:31.900540+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:04:31.899300+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ohio-state/living-environment/housing/lane-avenue" for 66.249.66.163 at 2014-03-06 13:04:31 +0000
2014-03-06T13:04:32.074973+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (168.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:04:32.074973+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (168.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:04:32.187898+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 281.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:04:32.187898+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 281.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:04:32.193694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ohio-state/living-environment/housing/lane-avenue host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=367e0d48-437c-4f89-adf1-24c6c6a8ea77 fwd="66.249.66.163" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=297ms status=200 bytes=65259
2014-03-06T13:07:02.026465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/duquesne-university host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=a4f00298-e2d8-4a22-bad8-cc36ee624593 fwd="66.249.66.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=510
2014-03-06T13:07:02.023719+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/duquesne-university" for 66.249.66.204 at 2014-03-06 13:07:02 +0000
2014-03-06T13:07:02.023719+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/duquesne-university" for 66.249.66.204 at 2014-03-06 13:07:02 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:08.419246+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pace-university/living-environment/food/hows-the-off-campus-food" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:08 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:08.419246+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pace-university/living-environment/food/hows-the-off-campus-food" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:08 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:08.421032+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:08.421032+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:08.421032+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"pace-university", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"food", "question_id"=>"hows-the-off-campus-food"}
2014-03-06T13:08:08.421032+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"pace-university", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"food", "question_id"=>"hows-the-off-campus-food"}
2014-03-06T13:08:08.584296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pace-university/living-environment/food/hows-the-off-campus-food host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=facdb16f-8330-4cfe-aa63-0265a9691ebd fwd="157.55.32.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=165ms status=200 bytes=61861
2014-03-06T13:08:08.542268+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (114.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:08.542268+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (114.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:08.576926+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 150.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.034264+00:00 app[web.
1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (164.3ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:08.863596+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:08.863596+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"tulane", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"food", "question_id"=>"is-there-anything-that-makes-this-program-special"}
2014-03-06T13:08:08.863596+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"tulane", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"food", "question_id"=>"is-there-anything-that-makes-this-program-special"}
2014-03-06T13:08:08.863596+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:08.862324+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tulane/living-environment/food/is-there-anything-that-makes-this-program-special" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:08 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:09.148944+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 279.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.148944+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 279.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.500828+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-hawaii-manoa/social-life/parties/what-was-your-favorite-class" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:09 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:09.500828+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-hawaii-manoa/social-life/parties/what-was-your-favorite-class" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:09 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:09.711714+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 209ms (Views: 203.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.711714+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 209ms (Views: 203.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.502100+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:09.502164+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:09.993347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/university-of-houston host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=fc016acd-36ad-4156-bb58-bce202badc94 fwd="157.55.32.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=514
2014-03-06T13:08:09.991693+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-houston" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:09 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:09.991693+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-houston" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:09 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:08.576926+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 150.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.502355+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"university-of-hawaii-manoa", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"parties", "question_id"=>"what-was-your-favorite-class"}
2014-03-06T13:08:08.862324+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tulane/living-environment/food/is-there-anything-that-makes-this-program-special" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:08:08 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:09.502355+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"university-of-hawaii-manoa", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"parties", "question_id"=>"what-was-your-favorite-class"}
2014-03-06T13:08:09.626936+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (118.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.034264+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (164.3ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.626936+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (118.2ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.715189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/university-of-hawaii-manoa/social-life/parties/what-was-your-favorite-class host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=1b674464-ad91-42e1-9895-5b852cdfbb0b fwd="157.55.32.39" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=218ms status=200 bytes=63771
2014-03-06T13:08:58.846461+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/duquesne-university/academics/professors
/1" for 66.249.66.96 at 2014-03-06 13:08:58 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:58.846461+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/duquesne-university/academics/professors/1" for 66.249.66.96 at 2014-03-06 13:08:58 +0000
2014-03-06T13:08:58.850683+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"duquesne-university", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:08:58.850622+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"duquesne-university", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:08:58.850579+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:58.850259+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:08:59.274113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/duquesne-university/academics/professors/1 host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=448834a7-934d-4545-9fc6-e883168c62fc fwd="66.249.66.96" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=437ms status=200 bytes=63272
2014-03-06T13:08:59.225228+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (363.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:59.225228+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (363.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:59.266395+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 415ms (Views: 405.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:59.266395+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 415ms (Views: 405.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:08:09.152472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/tulane/living-environment/food/is-there-anything-that-makes-this-program-special host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=3b9480cd-520e-4751-9443-34991fa24d48 fwd="157.55.32.39" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=293ms status=200 bytes=62271
2014-03-06T13:10:59.228743+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.228804+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"carnegie-mellon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"classes", "question_id"=>"how-often-do-you-desire-to-go-to-class"}
2014-03-06T13:10:59.228743+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.227703+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/carnegie-mellon/academics/classes/how-often-do-you-desire-to-go-to-class" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.227703+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/carnegie-mellon/academics/classes/how-often-do-you-desire-to-go-to-class" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.228804+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"carnegie-mellon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"classes", "question_id"=>"how-often-do-you-desire-to-go-to-class"}
2014-03-06T13:10:59.349293+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (114.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.442981+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 214ms (Views: 208.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.442981+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 214ms (Views: 208.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.349293+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (114.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.724234+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/about-college/academics/who-are-the-people-involved-in-teaching-a-class" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.724234+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/about-college/academics/who-are-the-people-involved-in-teaching-a-class" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.725411+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#disqus_about_college as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.731561+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/disqus_about_college.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.725411+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#disqus_about_college as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.725411+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"section"=>"academics", "question_id"=>"who-are-the-people-involved-in-teaching-a-class"}
2014-03-06T13:10:59.725555+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"section"=>"academics", "question_id"=>"who-are-the-people-involved-in-teaching-a-class"}
2014-03-06T13:10:59.731561+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/disqus_about_college.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.768289+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 41.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.768289+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 41.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.911700+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tulane/social-life/social-atmosphere/1" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.912969+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.912969+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"tulane", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"social-atmosphere", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:10:59.912969+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:10:59.911700+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/tulane/social-life/social-atmosphere/1" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:10:59 +0000
2014-03-06T13:10:59.912969+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"tulane", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"social-atmosphere", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:11:00.155248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/tulane/social-life/social-atmosphere/1 host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=d74d3358-513a-4370-93fb-c3a7411e29a5 fwd="157.56.229.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=247ms status=200 bytes=62365
2014-03-06T13:11:00.149861+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 231.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:00.115191+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (196.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:00.115191+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (196.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:00.149861+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 231.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.450442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/carnegie-mellon/academics/classes/how-often-do-you-desire-to-go-to-class host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=e4731073-d249-461d-93d1-d455ab7f7ff3 fwd="157.56.229.244" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=222ms status=200 bytes=63682
2014-03-06T13:11:38.101230+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/uc-berkeley/living-environment/campus/how-valuable-do-you-think-your-degree-is" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:11:38 +0000
2014-03-06T13:11:38.101230+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/uc-berkeley/living-environment/campus/how-valuable-do-you-think-your-degree-is" for 157.55.32.39 at 2014-03-06 13:11:38 +0000
2014-03-06T13:11:38.102186+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:11:38.102186+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:11:38.102186+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"uc-berkeley", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"campus", "question_id"=>"how-valuable-do-you-think-your-degree-is"}
2014-03-06T13:11:38.302848+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (193.9ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:38.302848+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (193.9ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:38.102186+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"uc-berkeley", "section1"=>"living-environment", "section2"=>"campus", "question_id"=>"how-valuable-do-you-think-your-degree-is"}
2014-03-06T13:11:38.341128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/uc-berkeley/living-environment/campus/how-valuable-do-you-think-your-degree-is host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=3cd78753-7ffa-453b-a799-37229d49022d fwd="157.55.32.39" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=244ms status=200 bytes=63171
2014-03-06T13:11:38.339250+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 230.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2014-03-06T13:11:38.339250+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 230.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2014-03-06T13:10:59.771121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/about-college/academics/who-are-the-people-involved-in-teaching-a-class host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=6e88978c-35e3-4a85-964d-18b8d558a372 fwd="157.56.229.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=30466
2014-03-06T13:13:11.774392+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/indiana-university-of-pennsylvania/social-life/kids/what-are-you-doing-now" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:13:11 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:11.774392+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/indiana-university-of-pennsylvania/social-life/kids/what-are-you-doing-now" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:13:11 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:11.775821+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:13:11.775821+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:13:11.775987+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"indiana-university-of-pennsylvania", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"kids", "question_id"=>"what-are-you-doing-now"}
2014-03-06T13:13:11.775987+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"indiana-university-of-pennsylvania", "section1"=>"social-life", "section2"=>"kids", "question_id"=>"what-are-you-doing-now"}
2014-03-06T13:13:11.970827+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (189.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:11.970827+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (189.5ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.005107+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 229ms (Views: 224.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.005107+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 229ms (Views: 224.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.286933+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-hawaii-manoa/academics/difficulty/are-you-well-prepared-for-your-career" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:13:12 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:12.286933+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/university-of-hawaii-manoa/academics/difficulty/are-you-well-prepared-for-your-career" for 157.56.229.244 at 2014-03-06 13:13:12 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:12.288167+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:13:12.288167+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as */*
2014-03-06T13:13:12.288167+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"university-of-hawaii-manoa", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"difficulty", "question_id"=>"are-you-well-prepared-for-your-career"}
2014-03-06T13:13:12.288167+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"university-of-hawaii-manoa", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"difficulty", "question_id"=>"are-you-well-prepared-for-your-career"}
2014-03-06T13:13:12.491630+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (197.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.491630+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (197.0ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.557734+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 263.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.557734+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 263.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:12.562345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/university-of-hawaii-manoa/academics/difficulty/are-you-well-prepared-for-your-career host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=d1b1bb13-ed95-41f1-ba99-992822e93bc1 fwd="157.56.229.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=279ms status=200 bytes=63792
2014-03-06T13:13:17.025820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=54c4da82-30c7-47e5-b4df-f40dc1f9ec07 fwd="194.74.226.190" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=301 bytes=486
2014-03-06T13:13:17.021316+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:17 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:17.021316+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:17 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:18.914396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon/academics/professors/1 host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=3583fb1d-153f-49cd-add8-58527ee63ce8 fwd="194.74.226.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=919
2014-03-06T13:13:18.900598+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon/academics/professors/1" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:18 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:18.900598+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon/academics/professors/1" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:18 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:18.903215+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as HTML
2014-03-06T13:13:18.903215+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as HTML
2014-03-06T13:13:18.903215+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"favicon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:13:18.903215+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"favicon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:13:18.909574+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:18.909574+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:18.909816+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
2014-03-06T13:13:18.909942+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <% description "#{@question}" %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <div id="college_pages_css">
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_college_pages_disqus_normal_html_erb__3999814205483227852_70309896071260'
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912266+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <% description "#{@question}" %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <div id="college_pages_css">
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_college_pages_disqus_normal_html_erb__3999814205483227852_70309896071260'
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.084944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.collegeinsideview.com request_id=ba33d6a9-5860-4beb-ad0d-dc8c5f485f3c fwd="194.74.226.190" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=19ms status=301 bytes=486
2014-03-06T13:13:19.068533+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:19 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:19.068692+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:19 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:19.938392+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon/academics/professors/1" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:19 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:19.938392+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/favicon/academics/professors/1" for 194.74.226.190 at 2014-03-06 13:13:19 +0000
2014-03-06T13:13:19.940462+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as HTML
2014-03-06T13:13:19.940747+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CollegePagesController#disqus_normal as HTML
2014-03-06T13:13:19.940958+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"favicon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:13:19.940958+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"college"=>"favicon", "section1"=>"academics", "section2"=>"professors", "question_id"=>"1"}
2014-03-06T13:13:19.948014+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:19.948014+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2014-03-06T13:13:19.948014+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
2014-03-06T13:13:19.948014+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) %>
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <% description "#{@question}" %>
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <div id="college_pages_css">
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_college_pages_disqus_normal_html_erb__3999814205483227852_70309896071260'
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) %>
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <% description "#{@question}" %>
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <div id="college_pages_css">
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_college_pages_disqus_normal_html_erb__3999814205483227852_70309896071260'
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-06T13:13:19.950671+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn static assets true on production.rb

In /config/environments/production. set:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Please add bellow code snippet in  config/application.rb
    <pre> config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false </code>

Comment: @AdamZerner If this is not working then just let me know and also you can see the log then it will give more info to fix this precompile issue.

Comment: did you mean to use a `<pre>` tag, or a `</code>` tag? Also, I posted the results of `heroku logs --tail`.

Comment: No, i put <pre> and <code> tag to format the code snippet in comment section but it was not working. Anyway, your issue arise due to @college have not any result so that it was nil. You can see it at app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb line no 1. Please check there nil first. By using like  <%= content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) if @college.present? %>

Comment: I made the changes to `application.rb`, and it still doesn't work. I don't think that there's a problem with the `@college` variable. If you go to school's pages, all the data loads, the title works, and everything works in development.

Comment: Your issue is arise due to following reason: 1. @college  is nil. OR 2.@college have not any attribute like 'name' You can check here <br/> <pre> ]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
1: <% content_for(:title, "#{@college.name} Student Reviews" + " | #{params[:section1]} | #{params[:section2]}".titleize) %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <% description "#{@question}" %>
2014-03-06T13:13:18.912462+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/college_pages/disqus_normal.html.erb:1</pre>